# I tried predicting on part of the dataset, but why does it keep predicting on the whole dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, linear-regression, prediction

So I build a lm model in R on 65OOO rows and I want to see only the predictions for the first ten rows in order to see how good my model predicts. Below you can see the code I wrote to execute this but it keeps predicting the values of all 65000 rows. Is someone able to help me?

```
test_data <- mydata[1:10,] 
test_data<-subset(test_data,select = -c(24)) #delete column which i try to predict
predict(lm_model109,new=test_data)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your code looks fin as for as the information you've provided. Could you (a) verify `nrow(test_data)`, (b) If you assign the result, `pred <- predict(...), verify `length(pred)`, (c) make sure everything is spelled correctly, and (d) provide a bit more code? What modeling function did you use? How did you call it? etc.

Comment: How did you build you `lm_model109` object. Did you use a formula syntax? Did you have `$` in your formula? That's a common mistake. Really hard to give any specific solutions without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: The second argument to predict should be "newdata" rather than "new". It's possible that the partial matching isn't matching this as you expect because predict.lm also takes the ... argument

Comment: @GregorThomas can u please answer to the other question I asked on my profile. I am really stuck

Comment: Can't really help on that one without a reproducible example.

Comment: @GregorThomas lm_model2002 <- lm(mydata$`AC: Volume` ~ `Market Area (L1)`,data=mydata)
summary(lm_model2002) #0.1126
predict(lm_model2002,data.frame(`Market Area (L1)`=="Algeria")) and still it keeps predicting all 65OOO rows

Comment: @MrFlick see comment above

Comment: @Miff see new comment

Comment: @Lucasjansens please edit new information into your question so it's all presented in one place and formatted nicely - don't just put things in comments. Also editing your question will bump it to the top of the "Active Questions" queue

Comment: You should never have `$` or data.frame names in your formula. Try `lm_model2002 <- lm(\`AC: Volume\` ~ \`Market Area (L1)\`, data=mydata)`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the words newdata and not new. It just ignores that line with the error and predicts the training data so    predict(lm_model109,newdata=test_data)

Comment: Your answer was covered in the question comments. Either attribute your answer to the person who commented, or explain why your answer differs. Thanks